# How to call different api domain(backend) from my Angular-cli app using maven eirslett frontend plugin?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors, http-proxy

I have created a maven web project using eirslett frontend-maven-plugin,
it allows me to install node, node_modules by itself, I have created an angular-cli project for the same, there is also a spring boot standalone application which I'm using to consume rest services.

I have configured a proxy-config.json & package.json as follows:

**proxy-config.json**

```
"/api": {
    "target": "http://someipaddress:8080",
    "secure": false
}
```

**package.json**

```
...

"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
...
```

Everything works fine when I simply do **npm start** which typically calls **ng serve** for Dev env, it can consume the data from my backend api.

But the problem occurs when you do maven build where it runs the ng build for deployments, there seems the problem occurs with **CORS** , and the web pack won't treat the ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json since it is not running any production server(typically node server) and web pack won't bundle these configurations into any of the bundles.

Could you please help me with an approach / any additional configuration that I need to follow for this scenario. How can I let my Frontend communicate with Backend API and consume its rest services, the WAR that contains all the bundled dist folder that will be deployed in a web server typically tomcat?

If you have come across this issue, could you share how you figured out this scenario, any resources/links or examples can help me a lot in solving this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the `proxy.conf.json` is **exclusively for development purposes**, in production you won't run `ng serve` or something similar.

When going into production you typically execute the build script `ng build --prod` which creates a bunch of **static files** in a `dist` folder. Those files should be deployed to your production folder.

Inside there is your app and when served by the browser, under the same domain (say https://mysampleapp.com) the frontend files as well as the backend API is being served.
Meaning to call something like https://mysampleapp.com or https://mysampleapp.com/index.html serves the static files and calling something like https://mysampleapp.com/api/v1/people calls the backend API (the location of the API clearly on your app).

Now if you load up the app using the url https://mysampleapp.com and the app internally usually makes requests like this `/api/v1/people` (without indicating a fully qualified hostname etc), then everything should work just fine and there shouldn't be any CORS issues.

The exact configuration you have to do really depends on the server (IIS, jBoss, Apache, Nginx) you're using and the deployment strategy (different location for frontend/backend, like frontend on some Apache/Nginx which then forwards to the backend which runs on IIS/jBoss/Node,...).

I'm going to write up something on this as many ppl have similar concerns and questions (I just don't have enough time atm). There's a **talk by Dan Wahlin** from NGConf which touches this topic. He uses Docker, but anyway, from a conceptual point of view this is applicable to every environment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=socWfhPJptE